# Reading JSON with different repeating keys and printing the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and I come across reading a json using python and i got stuck with the following not knowing how to deal with situations like this. I really appreciate your help.

I'm using python 3.6 and JSON file format is as shown below

## JSON:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-07-03 13:05:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2019-07-03 13:05:00": {
            "1. open": "137.4500",
            "2. high": "137.5000",
            "3. low": "137.2064",
            "4. close": "137.5000",
            "5. volume": "0"
        },
        "2019-07-03 13:00:00": {
            "1. open": "137.4800",
            "2. high": "137.6000",
            "3. low": "137.2400",
            "4. close": "137.4500",
            "5. volume": "759357"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:55:00": {
            "1. open": "137.4300",
            "2. high": "137.5100",
            "3. low": "137.4015",
            "4. close": "137.4720",
            "5. volume": "371471"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:50:00": {
            "1. open": "137.3750",
            "2. high": "137.4500",
            "3. low": "137.2800",
            "4. close": "137.4333",
            "5. volume": "222396"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:45:00": {
            "1. open": "137.4100",
            "2. high": "137.4700",
            "3. low": "137.3200",
            "4. close": "137.3727",
            "5. volume": "248270"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:40:00": {
            "1. open": "137.3000",
            "2. high": "137.4128",
            "3. low": "137.2900",
            "4. close": "137.4100",
            "5. volume": "177767"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:35:00": {
            "1. open": "137.3200",
            "2. high": "137.3700",
            "3. low": "137.2600",
            "4. close": "137.3000",
            "5. volume": "194017"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:30:00": {
            "1. open": "137.3797",
            "2. high": "137.4250",
            "3. low": "137.3100",
            "4. close": "137.3100",
            "5. volume": "148587"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:25:00": {
            "1. open": "137.4400",
            "2. high": "137.4500",
            "3. low": "137.3600",
            "4. close": "137.3750",
            "5. volume": "163235"
        },
        "2019-07-03 12:20:00": {
            "1. open": "137.2300",
            "2. high": "137.4650",
            "3. low": "137.1900",
            "4. close": "137.4400",
            "5. volume": "241906"
        },
}
}
```

Code I have tried:

### Python

```
import json
with open("d:/Python Projects/myjason3.json") as f:
    j1 = json.load(f)
    
    for data in j1['Time Series (5min)']:
        
        print([data]['1. open'])
```

I want to print value of key '1.open' under every time series value such as '2019-07-03 13:05:00'.
The error I'm receiving is :

```
 print([data]['1. open'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error comes from the brackets around `data`: `print(data['1. open'])`.

`[data]` creates a list of only one element, `data`, while you want to access the `data` dictionary directly.

Furthermore, you iterate on a dictionary, which yields the keys and not the values; try with: `for data in j1['Time Series (5min)'].values():`

Comment: thank you for your reply. Now I understand where I was doing wrong. Is there any other way without using values() or items() methods?

Comment: Well, you could do `for k in j1['Time Series (5min)']: print(j1['Time Series (5min)'][k]['1. open'])` but it looks worse to me. Iterating on a dictionary can mean several things and having the `values()` method makes it explicit (which is better than implicit).

Comment: Understand. Thank you for your help and quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You're not referencing the data dictionary properly.
You should be able to iterate through the `'Time Series (5min)'` key values like this:

```
for timestamp, values in j1['Time Series (5min)'].items():
    print(timestamp, values['1. open'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Is there any other way without using items() method?

Comment: `.items()` returns the key and related values, you can iterate over the `'Time Series (5min)'` keys only with `.keys()` if you prefer.  Then you'll have to access the values separately as needed.

Comment: as @monkut said you can iterate over the dict using either  ´.values()´, ´.keys()´ or´.items()´ (´.iteritems()´ in python <= 2.7) that will give you only the values in the dict, only the keys or both. The most common (more pythonic and suggested) way to iterate over a dict is using ´.items()´ .(https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for documentation)

Answer (score 0):

`for data in j1['Time Series (5min)']:` will iterate over the keys (dates) of your dict, not over the actual data.

`[data]['1. open']` translates to (ie in the first iteration) to `["2019-07-03 13:05:00", ]['1. open']`, so you are trying to access a list of strings (`["2019-07-03 13:05:00", ]`) by key (`'1. open'`).

To iterate over keys *and* values of a dict Python's way is to use `dict.items()` api:

```
import json
with open("d:/Python Projects/myjason3.json") as f:
    j1 = json.load(f)
    for datetime_key, data in j1['Time Series (5min)'].items():
        print(data['1. open'])
```

Comment: Good explanation.Thank you for your kind reply. Is there any other way without using items() method?